# Is there a way to enable/disable searching on a datatable by an specific event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable, icheck

I'm trying to disable the seaching field on a datatable when an specific radio button is selected.

I'using icheck plugin

I was thinking of using the blur even or this
My html

```
<div class="box-tools pull-right">
    <label for="rbn_buscar_codigo">
        <input type="radio" name="buscar_por" class="flat-red" id="rbn_buscar_codigo">
        <strong>Código</strong>
    </label>
    <label for="rbn_buscar_linea">
        <input type="radio" name="buscar_por" class="flat-red" id="rbn_buscar_linea">
        <strong>Línea</strong>
    </label>
    <label for="rbn_buscar_seccion">
        <input type="radio" name="buscar_por" class="flat-red" id="rbn_buscar_seccion">
        <strong>Sección</strong>
    </label>
    <label for="rbn_buscar_descripcion">
        <input type="radio" name="buscar_por" class="flat-red" id="rbn_buscar_descripcion">
        <strong>Descripción</strong>
    </label>
    <label for="rbn_buscar_todos">
        <input type="radio" name="buscar_por" class="flat-red" id="rbn_buscar_todos">
        <strong>Todos</strong>
    </label>
</div>
```

My Js

```
$('#rbn_buscar_codigo').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    $('#postTable').DataTable({
        'searching': false,
        'language': {
            'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
        }
    })
})
```

In the documentation there's a way to destroy the datatable .destroy() but i dont know how to create it again when that radiobutton is uncheck and another is selected

Answer (score 0):

I did this, not the best solution but it's suppoused that they will get diferent data for the diferent urls

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({
    'searching': false,
    'language': {
      'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
    }
  })
  $('#rbn_buscar_codigo').on('ifChecked', function (event) {

    tablaBusqueda.destroy()
    alert('tabla codigo')
    tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({
      'searching': false,
      'language': {
        'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
    })
  })
  $('#rbn_buscar_descripcion').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    tablaBusqueda.destroy()
    alert('tabla descripcion')
    tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({

      'language': {
        'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
    })
  })
  $('#rbn_buscar_linea').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    tablaBusqueda.destroy()
    alert('tabla linea')
    tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({

      'language': {
        'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
    })
  })
  $('#rbn_buscar_seccion').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    tablaBusqueda.destroy()
    alert('tabla seccion')
    tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({

      'language': {
        'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
    })
  })
  $('#rbn_buscar_todos').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    tablaBusqueda.destroy()
    alert('tabla todos')
    tablaBusqueda = $('#postTable').DataTable({

      'language': {
        'url': '../plugins/dataTables.spanish.lang'
      }
    })
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching div id is example_filter. Just simply hide the div using jquery when the radio button is checked.